# MVC Displaying error messages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf

I am trying to find a way to pass error messages back to my view from my controller.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.splittingFileMessage = "Splitting File...";
        ViewBag.startBatchMessage = "Start Batch Processing : ";
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        var numberRecordsPerFile = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NumberRecordsPerFile"]);
        var inputFileFolder = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InputFileFolder"];

        var batchSplitterClient = new SplitterServiceClient();
        var batchSplitterResponse = 
            batchSplitterClient.SplitFile(new BatchSplitterRequest
            {
                FilePath = inputFileFolder, 
                NumberOfRecordsPerFile = numberRecordsPerFile
            });
        var numberOfMessages = batchSplitterResponse.NumberOfMessages;

        if (batchSplitterResponse.Result.ResultCode == 200)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Progress");
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.error = "test error";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
```

So you can see in my Httppost method I am trying to set an error message i.e. ViewBag.error if it occurs in my WCF call.

But in my view on initial load ofcourse this hasn't been set.

I my view I have

```
<div class="errors">
        <%: ViewBag.error %>
</div>
```

But on initial page load the error comes up on ViewBag.error

```
The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.IO.TextWriter.Write(string, params object[])' and 'System.IO.TextWriter.Write(char[])'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[HandleError(View = "Error")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
        int u = Convert.ToInt32("");// Error line
        return View();
    }
}
```

HandleError Attribute at Action Method Level

```
[HandleError(View = "Error")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
    int u = Convert.ToInt32("");// Error line
    return View();
}
```

Defining HandleError Attribute at Global Level

We can also apply the HandleError Attribute at the global level by registering it in the Global.asax in Application_Start event.

Example

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute(), 2); //by default added


    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute
    {
        View = "Error"
    }, 1);
}
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

Error Page

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Error";
}
<h2>
    Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request.
    <br />
    Error :
</h2>
<p>
     @Model.Exception
</p>
```

Enabling Custom Error Handling

To enable custom error handling in the application by the HandleError attribute, we must add a CustomErrors element within the system.web section of web config.

Output

Catch Specific Type of Error

The ExceptionType property can help us to catch a specific type of error. For example, if we want to catch only an ApplicationException type of exception then we can define the ExceptionType.

```
[HandleError(ExceptionType = typeof(ApplicationException), View = "Error")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
    int u = Convert.ToInt32(""); // Error line
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try casting it as a string

```
<div class="errors">
        <%: (string)ViewBag.error %>
</div>
```

or `ViewBag.error.ToString()`

Answer (score -1):

User HandleErrorAttribute and Error Page or  Elmah for Validation errors add to Modelstate and Use Error  Page to look for Validation errors and display

If it answered your question, tick right mark on left side , to make it answered